# What are the differences between Fail2Ban and BFD (Brute Force Detection)

Tags: iptables, firewall, fail2ban, brute-force-attacks, afp

I have used both Fail2Ban and BFD, typically I go with Fail2Ban on servers running IPTables, and BFD when servers are running APF.

Are there any major differences between these 2 services? What are the strengths and Weaknesses between these 2 programs and compatibility issues?.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use much BFD. There are a couple of reasons, mostly because I find it limited compared to Fail2Ban. For instance: the BFD's purpose is to find **failed login attempts**, while Fail2Ban is to find **pretty much anything** in a log file, allowing you to create your own rules. Another reason is that BFD doesn't run as daemon. Instead, you have to schedule it through cron.

I use Fail2Ban to block brute-force attempts in websites made with WordPress, SSH, and FTP. Great tool, by the way.

Cya!